# ССП неоднородного состава:

Tags: ссп

Верно ли найдено в тексте ССП неоднородного состава?

Янгель старался изучать языки, и это ему не раз уже пригодилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ССП неоднородного состава найдено верно. *Янгель старался изучать языки, и это ему не раз уже пригодилось*. Это ССП состоит из двух неоднородных предложений, между которыми нужно поставить запятую при наличии союза "и".